# Not able to build fuse-dfs to mount HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fuse

My Hadoop version is 2.5.2.

I want to mount Hadoop with fuse. I have tried two methods, but both failed. One method is in:

```
HADOOP_HOME: ant compile-c++-libhdfs -Dlibhdfs=1`.
```

But it failed for it can't find `build.xml`.  The other method is in `hadoop-hdfs/target/native/main/native/fuse-dfs`, I execute `make` but still don't have fuse-dfs.

How should I build fuse-dfs so I can mount HDFS by fuse?

Comment: Don't you mean to ask how to build fuse-dfs?  If it is, can you provide more details like the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I want to build fuse-dfs. In the fuse-dfs directory to execute the make command, I expect to generate fuse-dfs tool.But i got nothing,and didn't have error infos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have Java and Maven installed and can build the other Hadoop components.  After that you run:

```
$ mvn package -Pnative -Drequire.fuse=true -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

This instruction is in later READMEs for fuse-dfs (hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/fuse-dfs/doc/README)

> BUILDING
>
> fuse-dfs executable can be built by setting `require.fuse` option to true using Maven. For example:
>     in HADOOP_PREFIX: `mvn package -Pnative -Drequire.fuse=true -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`
>
> The executable `fuse_dfs` will be located at HADOOP_PREFIX/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/main/native/fuse-dfs/

but the 2.5.2 source refers to the older instructions.

My build environment is a CentOS 6 server.  I added the additional packages mentioned in https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute under **Native libraries**:

> For RHEL (and hence also CentOS):
>
> yum -y install  lzo-devel  zlib-devel  gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake libtool openssl-devel fuse-devel cmake

References:

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute - build instructions